# jquery ui: is it possible to create a floating form?

Tags: jquery-ui

I know that I can create a dialog.
I know that I can create a form.

Is it possible to combine the two and make myself a dialogbox which makes a post to the same page?

Comment: Yes, jQuery UI dialogs can contain forms, or be part of forms.

Comment: Can you show me a code example? I actually call the .dialog() method on the div but I don't know which paramether can make it a form

Comment: It is not a matter of parameters, either the dialog contains a `<form>` element (or is a descendant of one) or it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery UI dialog display a div and its content as a dialog.

So if your div contains a `<form>` element it will displayed fine.

Code:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <form id="t2eForm" action="#">
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="t2e_w" name="t2eWrite" />
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("div#dialog").dialog({title: 'Demo'});
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NdhkL/